# How to match values of primary key and foreign key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am having a problem matching the values of my primary column from a table called "Course" and foreign key in my other table called "Curriculum". My table in sql server looks like this

---

```
COURSE TABLE
CourseID | CourseName | CourseCode
----------------------------------
8        | IT         | 62345
9        | BA         | 64738
10       | IS         | 62341
```

---

---

```
CURRICULUM TABLE
CourseCode     | CurriculumID | CourseID
----------------------------------------
62345          | 87           | 4
64738          | 98           | 5
62341          | 78           | 6
```

---

these values are imported in a website I made using asp.net. I uploaded the csv file there and then it will be added in the database, after that I get these values and it seems that the primary and foreign key doesn't match. I need a query that will match these both columns. Please help. I need my Curriculum table to look like this:

---

```
CURRICULUM TABLE
CourseCode     | CurriculumID | CourseID
----------------------------------------
62345              | 87           | 8
64738              | 98           | 9
62341              | 78           | 10
```

---

Comment: Based on what condition ,do you want to update the CourseID in CURRICULAM table?

Comment: I'm not quite sure yet. I'm thinking of adding another column to both tables that are same. And then from there, if both these tables have equal values, it should also have the same courseid? I really have no idea how to solve this yet. @UnnikrishnanR

Comment: Did you check the csv file? I think the old courseID mapping will be there in the csv..

Comment: Oh, I need to make an sql query to update the foreign key to match the primary key. But I don't know how to do it. @UnnikrishnanR

Comment: With out a common key or matching element , we can't idealy perform this update.

Comment: Looks like you need to change something in code which loads data into db from CSV or other sources.

Comment: how about something like this? @UnnikrishnanR

Comment: I need a sql query in order to update these tables. Is that even possible? @Serg

Comment: @Briana if you have a common column like coursecode in both table,you can perform the update.. see my answer.

Comment: @Briana please make the update in your Output table as well otherwise that will make confusion to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have course code in both the tables,you can use the below script.

```
UPDATE cu
SET cu.CourseID=c.CourseID
FROM Course c
 JOIN CURRICULUM  cu ON c.CourseCode=cu.CourseCode
```